# Returning JSON after a query in yii

Tags: php, json, rest, yii

I'm new to yii framework. I'm just trying to implement Restful APIs. In the simple case scenario (after following some tutorial) I've succeeded with this:

```
$result = [];
foreach($this->getData() as $record) {
    $result[] = $record->getAttributes();
}
return $result;
```

Note that `getData()` is a built-in method. Where when trying to use queries for more advanced scenarios, it's done this way:

```
$attributeNames = 'udid,model,appverionid';
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$command = $connection->createCommand('select ' . $attributeNames . ' from device');
$models = $command->queryAll();

$attributeNames = explode(',', $attributeNames);
$rows = array();
foreach ($models as $model) {
  $row = array();
  foreach ($attributeNames as $name) {
    $row[$name] = CHtml::value($model, $name);
  }
  $rows[] = $row;
}
return $rows;
```

Is that the best practice to return get JSON from queries results, or maybe it can be done in a better way?

**Update:**

The final response is returned from the following method:

```
private function sendAjaxResponse(AjaxResponseInterface $interface)
{
    $success = count($interface->getErrors()) === 0;
    $responseCode = $success ? 200 : 404;
    header("content-type: application/json", true, $responseCode);
    echo json_encode([
    'success' => $success,
    'data' => $interface -> getResponseData(),
    'errors' => $interface -> getErrors()
    ]);
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

And I found out that only these lines are sufficient:

```
$attributeNames = 'udid,model,appverionid';
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$command = $connection->createCommand('select ' . $attributeNames . ' from device');
$models = $command->queryAll();
return $models;
```

The other part (the nested loop) seems for encoding with relations ([see here](http://learnyii.blogspot.com/2011/07/yii-json-cjson-models-model-related.html)) Then my question is what is encoding with relations and when it is helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yii way of creating JSOn data is using CJson library

```
$query = "'select ' . $attributeNames . ' from device'";
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query);
$result = $command->queryAll();

$ret = array_values($result);

/* or ...
  $ret = array();
  foreach ($models as $model) {
      $ret = array();
      foreach ($attributeNames as $name) {
          $row[$name] = CHtml::value($model, $name);
      }
      $ret[] = $row;
  }
*/

echo CJSON::encode($ret);
Yii::app()->end();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need to encode the value before return

```
foreach ($models as $model) {
   $row = array();
   foreach ($attributeNames as $name) {
     $row[$name] = CHtml::value($model, $name);
   }
   $rows[] = $row;
}
return json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge, it's being encoded indeed, see my update.

Comment: well  if my answer was helpful please to rate it

Answer (score 0):

> **Very Simple!** Just add this line - `\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response:: FORMAT_JSON;` in your method at start and do other code 
>   normally.

**for example**,

```
public function actionHospitals()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response:: FORMAT_JSON;
    $hospitals = Hospitals::find()->select('speciality')->distinct()->all();
    return ['hospitals' => $hospitals];
}
```